# vue-material's md-table slot-scope rendering fails with beta8

Tags: javascript, vue-material

I have this pen demonstrating my problem.

https://codepen.io/sfyrious/pen/zWarZa

To me it looks like 1.0.0-beta-8 on vue-material is broken.

```
<div id="app">
  <md-table v-model="entries" md-card>
  <md-table-head>This table does not render.</md-table-head>
    <md-table-row slot="md-table-row" slot-scope="{ entry }" :key="entry.uid">
      <md-table-cell md-label="UID" md-sort-by="uid" md-numeric>{{ entry.uid }}</md-table-cell>
      <md-table-cell md-label="Name" md-sort-by="name">{{ entry.name }}</md-table-cell>
      <md-table-cell md-label="Alive?" md-sort-by="alive">{{ entry.alive }}</md-table-cell>
    </md-table-row> 
  </md-table> 
  <md-table md-card>
    <md-table-head>This table renders fine</md-table-head>
    <md-table-row v-for="entry in entries" :key="entry.uid">
      <md-table-cell md-label="UID">{{ entry.uid }}</md-table-cell>
      <md-table-cell md-label="Name">{{ entry.name }}</md-table-cell>
      <md-table-cell md-label="Alive?">{{ entry.alive }}</md-table-cell>
    </md-table-row> 
  </md-table> 
 </div>
```

-- separate js file

```
Vue.use(VueMaterial.default)

var myapp = {
      name: "myApplication",
      data: function data() {
        return {
          entries: {
            0 : {
              "uid" : 1,
              "name" : "Bill",
              "alive" : true
            },
            1 : {
              "uid" : 2,
              "name" : "Bob",
              "alive" : true
            },
            2 : {
              "uid" : 3,
              "name" : "Sally",
             "alive" : false
            }
       }
     }
   }  
}

var app = new Vue(myapp)
app.$mount("#app")
```

The first table won't render at all, but the second table renders fine. Any idea? What might be causing the trouble? I tried to remove anything that could break it otherwise. Help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that 'entries' should be an array instead of an object. And the slot-scope has to be { item }.

I was corrected by the good developers of vue-material!